# DB2: restore database returns error SQL2036N on Linux

Tags: db2, backup, db2-luw

I try to restore a DB2 database, but it says the return path is not valid.

This is what I tried:

```
db2 restore database gyczpas from "/home/db2inst1/GYCZPAS/PAS_BACKUP/GYCZPAS.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN0000.20170109092932.001" taken at 20170109092932 into gyczpas
SQL2036N  The path for the file or device "/home/db2inst1/GYCZPAS/PAS_BACKUP/GYCZPAS.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.CATN000" is not valid.
```

I used the same path during `RESTORE` that I used for the `BACKUP` command, but it fails. What could be the reason?

DB22 version: v9.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the file name, not the path for [RESTORE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0006242.html). Try something like the following - only specify the path:

```
db2 restore database gyczpas from "/home/db2inst1/GYCZPAS/PAS_BACKUP" taken at 20170109092932 into gyczpas
```